# Regex: multiple occurence of new line Tabbed outcome

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

I'm having a dataset which i need to get the values from in one line tabbed from eachother.

Say i have this dataset:

```
test
pizza

pudding
cheese


Newt
somethingelse

otherstuf


pokemon
somedate
derp
```

Notice the difference between the 2 and 1 new lines.

When there are 2 new lines a new row will be made
When there is 1 new line that "value" will be in the same row as empty value.
This dataset would become this:

```
test    pizza         pudding    cheese
Newt    somethingelse    otherstuf
pokemon    somedate     derp
```

Again notice the first line in this example where the empty row between `pizza` and `pudding` is 1 new line instead of 2.

I've tried matching on a new line with: `^\n` and replace with `\t` but this would get me everything tabbed on one line which is not what i want.. 
I'm using **sublime** for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest

```
(.)\R{1,2}+(?!\R)
```

and replace with `$1\t`. This way, you will match 1 to 2 linebreaks only and replace them with a tab. A `(.)` will make sure there is some data on the line before the first linebreak.

[image]

**Pattern details**:

- `(.)` - Group 1 capturing a character other than a newline
- `\R{1,2}+` - 1 or 2 linebreaks...
- `(?!\R)`  - ...that are not followed with a linebreak.

If you allow merging empty lines, you may try

```
(?<!\n)\R{1,2}+(?!\R)
```

and replace with a `\t`.

Then, to replace 3 linebreaks with one, use

```
\R{3}
```

and replace with `\r\n` or `\n`, or `\r`, depending on your OS/requirements.

Answer (score 0):

When you talk about a new-line you mean a blank-line otherwise reaching a blank-line needs checking for two new-line characters. That's true about 2 new-lines as well.

Find: `(?<!\s)\n(?=\S)|\n{2}`

Replace with: `\t`

[image]

*Just for showing off my template.*

Answer (score 0):

Choose the good newline sequence (according to your file) and use two passes. Example with a Windows newline sequence:

Use two passes:

- replace `\r\n` with `\t`
- replace `\t\t\t` with `\r\n`

Comment: @Baklap4: In this case you only have to use `\n` in place of `\r\n`.